# How to get latest 3 months data by default from complete data set

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, impala

I have a full year data set and I have developed a power bI report on it and I scheduled it.
I need to show up last 3 months data every time.

```
Column a   column b column c
a            1      2019-01-01
b            2      2019-02-01
c            3      2019-03-01
d            4      2019-04-01
e            5      2019-05-01
```

I am trying to get last 3 months data from above table by using hive query without hard coding the month name or month number in where condition.

like by using this kind of date function.

```
select add_month( month, max(month(COLUMN C)),-3) from tableA
```

Comment: column c is partition column in hive ?

Comment: No it's not a partition column

Answer (score 1):

Its [add_months](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

```
select * from tableA where columnc > add_months(columnc,-3)
```

if the columnc is not a string then cast it

```
select * from tableA where (cast(columnc as string),'yyyy-MM-dd') > add_months((cast(columnc as string),'yyyy-MM-dd'),-3)
```

Comment: Tried your query ....,got the  error   ... cast(startdate as string),'yyyy-MM-dd') > add_months(... ^ Encountered: COMMA Expected: AND, BETWEEN, DIV, GROUP, HAVING, ILIKE, IN, IREGEXP, IS, LIKE, LIMIT, NOT, OFFSET, OR, ORDER, REGEXP, RLIKE, UNION CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error